# Safe use of Update-FormatData?

Tags: powershell

In a custom PowerShell module, I have at the top of my module definition this code:

```
Update-FormatData -AppendPath (Join-Path $psscriptroot "*.ps1xml")
```

This is working fine as all `.ps1xml` files are loaded.

However, the module is sometimes loaded using `Import-Module MyModule -Force` (actually, this is in the install script of the module).

In this case, the call to `Update-FormatData` fails with this error :

```
Update-FormatData : There were errors in loading the format data file:
Microsoft.PowerShell, c:\pathto\myfile.Types.ext.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already present from "Microsoft.PowerShell".
At line:1 char:18
+ Update-FormatData <<<<  -AppendPath "c:\pathto\myfile.Types.ext.ps1xml"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-FormatData], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateFormatDataCommand
```

Is there a way to safely call this command?

I know I can call `Update-FormatData` with no parameters, and it will update any known `.ps1xml` file, but this would work only if the file has already been loaded.

Can I list somewhere the loaded format data files?

Here is a bit of background:

I'm building a custom module that is installed using a script. The install script looks like :

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact="High")]
param()
process {
    $target = Join-Path $PSHOME "Modules\MyModule"
    if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("$target","Deploying MyModule module"))
    {
        if(!(Test-Path $target)) { new-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target | Out-Null }
        get-ChildItem -Path (Split-Path ((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value).MyCommand.Path) | copy-Item -Destination $target -Force

        Write-Host -ForegroundColorWhite @"

The module has been installed. You can import it using :

    Import-Module MyModule

Or you can add it in your profile ($profile)
"@

        Write-Warning "To refresh any open PowerShell session, you should run ""Import-Module MyModule -Force"" to reload the module"

        Import-Module MyModule -Force

        Write-Warning "This session has been refreshed."
    }
}
```

MyModule defines, as first statement, this line :

```
Update-FormatData -AppendPath (Join-Path $psscriptroot "*.ps1xml")
```

As I updated my `$profile` to always load this module, the `Update-Path` command has been called when I run the install script. In the install script, I force import the module, which be fire again the module, and then, the `Update-Path` call

Comment: Why this question has been migrated? Isn't Powershell and scripting more suited on superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is use the `-erroraction` (alias `-ea` ) param:

```
Update-FormatData -AppendPath (Join-Path $psscriptroot "*.ps1xml") -force -ea SilentlyContinue
```

no error will be showed.

Comment: Christian, I know this parameter. But I don't like it because it will hide all errors, even actual errors on the initial load. I suppose the probability to fail is very very low in this specific case. It will probably be the way I'll choose. I'm still eager to find an actual solution.

Comment: @SteveB You can try to use a modulemanifest, if I remeber can do exactly what you need. Now I've no time to give you an example but a quick googling can help.

Comment: Probably this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878297(v=vs.85).aspx. I'll read it thanks